# Pull string from sql to java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to pull a first name and last name from a table in my SQL database. The queries work fine in SQL without the "as First" part and I know the db connection is fine since it works in every other part of the code.

The error I receive is that `table "First" does not exist`, but it should be looking at firstName and lastName for the table names, not First and Last.

Its inside of a for loop with "i", but those values are correct, playerid = i exists.

```
try {
    String query2 = " SELECT firstName as First from player "
            + "WHERE playerid = ?";
    PreparedStatement st2 = db.conn.prepareStatement(query);
    st2.setInt(1, i);
    ResultSet rs2 = st2.executeQuery();
    if (rs2.next()) {
        setFirstName(rs2.getString("First"));
    }

    String query3 = " SELECT lastName as Last from player "
            + "WHERE playerid = ?";
    PreparedStatement st3 = db.conn.prepareStatement(query);
    st3.setInt(1, i);
    ResultSet rs3 = st3.executeQuery();

    if (rs3.next()) {
        setLastName(rs3.getString("Last"));
    }
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: You're preparing `query` each time, not `query2` or `query3`. What is `query`?

Comment: You are correct. I was preparing the wrong query. Its from earlier code. That solved the problem. Don't know why I didn't notice. The error message said the table didn't exist, because the query it was prepping referred to a different table, not the one I needed. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code into something like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
try {
    ps = db.conn.prepareStatement("SELECT firstName, lastName from player "
        + "WHERE playerid = ?");

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PLAYERS /*<- or what is the loop condition?*/; i++) {

        ps.setInt(1, i);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            // should these methods really be called within a loop?
            setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
            setLastName(rs.getString("lastName"));
        }
        rs.close();
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
} finally {
    if (ps != null) {
        ps.close();
    }
}
```

Some considerations:

When you're using a `PreparedStatement` within a loop, you should create the statement once, *outside of the loop* and then only re-assign the bind variable(s) during each iteration.

You should minimize the number of queries you run against the DB; in your case you should select both the first and last name column in a single query.

It is important to close the resources you open up (the `PreparedStatement` in this case). My example shows how this is usually done (in the `finally` block) pre Java 7. Use the [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) if you're using a newer Java version.

Comment: It turns out my mistake was a simple one, but this code is definitely better than the way I did it. Too many SQL queries was making the code hard to track. This is simpler. Thank you.